# `\polymerdelim` issue with `tikz-external` crash

Tags: errors, chemfig, tikz-external

Error when i have both `tikz-external` and a `chemfig` molecule

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\tikzsetfigurename{figure_\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}.} % set figure names

\tikzset{external/system call={%
    lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape
    --halt-on-error
    --shell-escape
    --interaction=batchmode
    --jobname "\image" "\texsource"
    % --jobname "\image" \subfilename
}}

\tikzexternalize[
    up to date check={simple}, % faster check
    figure list={true}, % generate list of figures file
    prefix={./}
] % turn externalization on/off

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{external/remake next=true}

\chemfig{
    C(-[90,.5])(-[-90,.5])
    -C(-[90,.5])(-[-90,.5]Cl)
}

% Cant compile
% \chemfig{-[@{op,.25}]
%     C(-[90,.5])(-[-90,.5])
%     -C(-[90,.5])(-[-90,.5]Cl)
% -[@{cl,.75}]}
% \polymerdelim{op}{cl}

\end{document}
```

Must add that the error seems to appear on the first figure even tho it compiled fine in the absence of the second. it may seen that `\polymerdelim{op}{cl}` changes the behaviour of all `\chemfig` commands.

Gathered from `figure_0.0.0.log` (the first figure)

```
Runaway argument?
 
! File ended while scanning use of \tikzexternal@laTeX@collect@until@end@tikzpicture.
<inserted text> 
\par 
<*> \def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}
```

#### From MS-SPO

The error message probably is, when uncommenting the `% Cant compile` part:

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'lualatex -shell-escape --halt-on-
error --shell-escape --interaction=batchmode --jobname "./figure_0.0.0" "\def\t
ikzexternalrealjob{externalChemfig}\input{externalChemfig}"' did NOT result in
a usable output file './figure_0.0.0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:).
Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflat
ex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that
. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in './figure_
0.0.0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.
See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
```

It doesn't seem to change when:

- switching compiles from `pdflatex` to `lualatex`
- moving the `chemfig` package before `tikz`

While it DOES compile (pdflatex and lualatex) with this line kept being commented:

```
% \polymerdelim{op}{cl}
```

Comment: Can you please check my edit and modify as needed?

Comment: Thanks for the addition, most of it seems to checkup with what i see trying to compile, except it also does compile in lualatex with `% \polymerdelim{op}{cl}` commented, except it does not render correctly in either.

Comment: You need to disable externalisation for these pictures because `chemfig` relies on `remember picture` and that's incompatible with externalisation.

Comment: If you use `memoize` instead, it will compile without error (but it will still not externalise the un-externalisable). I don't know whether `robust-externalize` can do any better.